# Извлечь данные из словаря

Tags: python, list, словари

Путаюсь с вложенностью данных.
Допустим есть такой массив

```
list = [
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'abc': 123, 'def': 456, 'g': {'h': [7, 8, 9]}}}
]
```

В нем мне нужно достать данные из последнего списка **[7, 8, 9]**, допустим нужна только цифра **8**, как это сделать?

Comment: как достать 8 из [7,8,9] понятно? а как достать значение ключа из словаря?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list[0]['c']['g']['h'][1]
```

А вообще идея называть переменные именами, совпадающими с зарезервированными именами наводит на мысль, что книги по Python вы не читаете.